# Apache AuthBasic Module isn't working and recognized in Mamp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp, .htpasswd

On my local system i tried to get password protecting a directory with `.htaccess` running on Mamp 3.0.7.2 . The Apache version Mamp uses is Apache/2.2.29 (Unix). The httpd.conf file

```
/applications/mamp/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

contains the following active line:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
```

My testproject in

```
/applications/mamp/htdocs/sandbox/testproject/admin/.htaccess
```

contains following lines:

```
AuthBasic Basic
AuthName "Admin Area"
AuthUserFile /applications/mamp/htdocs/sandbox/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

the `.htpasswd` file was created one level beneath in the sandbox folder for testing purpose only with:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd adminuser
```

with pwd `.htpasswd` within the sandbox folder i've extracted the exact path to prevent any typos which lead to

```
/applications/mamp/htdocs/sandbox/.htpasswd
```

but when i try to access the `index.php` file in the admin folder i get the following in the browser:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

and the php_error.log outputs the following on every try:

```
[Mon Dec 29 11:23:30 2014] [alert] [client ::1] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sandbox/testproject/admin/.htaccess: Invalid command 'AuthBasic', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

But how could the AuthBasic command be misspelled or not included, cuz it actually is defined properly as shown above. :/

Comment: Its `AuthType Basic`

Comment: argh... i was blind, silly typo... thanks!

Comment: I was getting a similar error, my issue was a space in the path to the .htpasswd file. Enclosing it with quotes fixed it.